# Conditional probability of $E[X_{1}\mid X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_{n}]$

Tags: conditional-expectation

> Find conditional probability of $E[X_{1}|X_1+X_2+...+X_{n}]$ given the
>   fact that $X_{k}$ for all $k$ have finite expected value and all the
>   variables are independent and have the same distribution.

I guess the solution should follow quickly from one of the properties of the conditional probability. But I don't see any that would be helpful. So is applying the definition the right way?

Comment: Same expectation? Otherwise there is no simple answer.

Comment: Of course, sorry.

Comment: (*Typo: Same distribution, not only same expectation.) Then, by symmetry, $E(X_k\mid X_1+\cdots+X_n)=\frac1n(X_1+\cdots+X_n)$ for every $k$.